# javascript filter values from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to find is_Y === 'Y' object from like this code

```js
const tmpArray = [
    [{ "no": 1, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 2, "is_Y": "N", }],
    [{ "no": 3, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 3, "is_Y": "N", }],
    [{ "no": 4, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 5, "is_Y": "N", }, { "no": 6, "is_Y": "Y", }]
];

function findY(array) {
    return array.filter(function (item) {
        return item.filter(function (item2) {
           return item2.is_Y === 'Y';
         });
    });
}

console.log(findY(tmpArray));
```

result is

```
[
  [ { no: 1, is_Y: 'Y' } ],
  [ { no: 2, is_Y: 'N' } ],
  [ { no: 3, is_Y: 'Y' } ],
  [ { no: 3, is_Y: 'N' } ],
  [ { no: 4, is_Y: 'Y' } ],
  [ { no: 5, is_Y: 'N' }, { no: 6, is_Y: 'Y' } ]
]
```

but I'd like to get results format like below

```
[
  { no: 1, is_Y: 'Y' },
  { no: 3, is_Y: 'Y' },
  { no: 4, is_Y: 'Y' },
  { no: 6, is_Y: 'Y' } 
]
```

what shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix is to add an `flat()` before calling `filter()`:

```js
const tmpArray = [
    [{ "no": 1, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 2, "is_Y": "N", }],
    [{ "no": 3, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 3, "is_Y": "N", }],
    [{ "no": 4, "is_Y": "Y", }],
    [{ "no": 5, "is_Y": "N", }, { "no": 6, "is_Y": "Y", }]
];

function findY(array) {
    return array.flat().filter(item2 => item2.is_Y === 'Y')
}

console.log(findY(tmpArray));
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "no": 1,
    "is_Y": "Y"
  },
  {
    "no": 3,
    "is_Y": "Y"
  },
  {
    "no": 4,
    "is_Y": "Y"
  },
  {
    "no": 6,
    "is_Y": "Y"
  }
]
```

Comment: No need to perform `array.flatMap(e => e)`, you just need to flat the array with `array.flat()`

Comment: Ah your right, went to fast! THanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Thats my answer now :p Any how those were almost simultaneous posts

Answer (score 1):

Just `flat` the array before you filter.

```js
const tmpArray = [
  [{ no: 1, is_Y: "Y" }],
  [{ no: 2, is_Y: "N" }],
  [{ no: 3, is_Y: "Y" }],
  [{ no: 3, is_Y: "N" }],
  [{ no: 4, is_Y: "Y" }],
  [
    { no: 5, is_Y: "N" },
    { no: 6, is_Y: "Y" },
  ],
];

function findY(array) {
  return array.flat().filter((item) => item.is_Y === "Y");
}

console.log(findY(tmpArray));
```